# Обучение на кафедре

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, семантика

Можно ли, говоря о кафедре, иметь в виду студентов: *я обучался на кафедре религиоведения, он проходил обучение на кафедре композиции.*
Когда речь идёт о кафедре, подразумевают ведь исключительно преподавательско-профессорский состав? То есть можно только "преподавать на кафедре" или же со стороны студентов употребление этого понятия также вполне корректно?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что говорится в словарях о [кафедре](http://endic.ru/efremova/Kafedra-34847.html).

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
2. а) *перен.* Находящаяся в заведовании ученого самостоятельная область знания, **научная дисциплина как предмет преподавания в высшем учебном заведении.**
б) Структурное подразделение, объединяющее преподавателей и научных сотрудников данной области знания или научной дисциплины.

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
2. Структурное подразделение факультета высшего учебного заведения, объединяющее специалистов какой-либо отрасли науки, ведущих преподавательскую и научную работу. *Заседание кафедры. Избрать заведующего кафедрой органической химии.* // **Самостоятельная область знания как предмет преподавания в высшей школе.** *Кафедра русского языка филологического факультета. Стать профессором по кафедре романской филологии.*

Конечно, он **отучился на кафедре религиоведения** философского факультета, защитил кандидатскую, потом преподавал античную литературу в одном московском институте, почти не зная греческого и походя наверстывая латынь. [А. Н. Мурашов. Исполнитель // «Волга», 2015]

Мой отец, я с женой, дочь, внуки ― четыре поколения, которые лечатся у врача, или четвертое поколение, которое учится у учительницы в школе, или четвертое поколение, которое **учится на кафедре филологии** в таком-то институте... [Борис Любимов. Три главные темы в жизни ― Церковь, литература и театр (2015)]

Курс культурологии, который **изучается на кафедре гуманитарных и социальных наук**, был введен с целью восполнить пробелы в знании требований воинского и гражданского этикета… [Ирина Прусс. Сделайте мне красивше // «Знание-сила», 2013]

Терлецкий знал, что он делает: **учился он на кафедре**, руководимой Таммом, а кандидатскую диссертацию защищал под руководством Леонтовича. [Геннадий Горелик. Ученый раб, свободный духом // «Знание - сила», 2008]

Предполагается разработать целую систему отбора талантливых ребят со всей России для их дальнейшего **обучения на кафедре физики** в университете «Дубна». [Новости // «Встреча» (Дубна), 2003.04.02]

*Я обучался на кафедре религиоведения, он проходил обучение на кафедре композиции* — я думаю, что так говорить вполне грамотно.